# Geo-Coordinates in custom object

Tags: geolocation

I need a latitude and longitude field in one of my custom object. I tried data integration rule but it is available only for account,contact and lead. How can i populate coordinate in custom object based on address field in that object.

Comment: External service + custom solution?

Comment: can you explain briefly ?

Comment: its not clear from your question what you need? You are unable to populate geo-coordinates manually? or else you want geo-coordinates populated automatically? Can you explain in detail what exactly is needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to subscribe to an external service like Google Geocoding API.  Then you will need to write Apex triggers to geocode your custom object addresses by calling the API methods, and then you can store the coordinates in the records.